# Realtime database doesn't give me the push().key on Android, works fine on iOS

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, react-native-firebase

On Android the push reference is undefined and so is the key. Works fine on iOS.

I'm using react-native-firebase 11.0.0.

**listKey is undefined** on row 4. The list is added to the database just fine with the push command but since I don't get the **listKey** the rest of the code doesn't work. As stated before, no problems at all with iOS. Reading from the database works fine on Android.

I've tried:

1. updating react-native-firebase to 11.4.1, no change
2. downloading the repo to another folder and do **npm install** without the package-lock.json (fixed 11.0.0 in package.json)
3. `const listPushRef = await listsRef.push({ user: getUser(), name: listName });` gives an error that it can't run .then() on undefined.

Any ideas?

Code:

```
export const addList = async (listName, freeCategory) => {
  const listsRef = database().ref(`lists`);
  const listPushRef = listsRef.push({ user: getUser(), name: listName });
  const listKey = listPushRef.key;

  const usersListsRef = database().ref(`users/${getUser()}/lists`);
  const usersLists = await usersListsRef.once('value').then(snapshot => snapshot.val() || []);
  usersLists.push(listKey);
  usersListsRef.set(usersLists);

  const userRef = database().ref(`users/${getUser()}`);
  const user = await userRef.once('value').then(snapshot => snapshot.val());
  const listConfigurations = user.listConfigurations || {};
  listConfigurations[listKey] = [
    {
      id: freeCategory,
      isCategory: true,
      compareTo: [],
    },
  ];
  userRef.update({ listConfigurations });

  return listKey;
};
```

Comment: Pssst should it be awaited? Some browsers will play nice with this rule but if it's undefined, likely the promise hadn't returned and you skipped it? Other browsers behaved normal to this tho?

Comment: Try running a console.log on listsRef and determining if it gets defined in time in android or try an await in front of it? :O

Comment: I have tried an await in front of it, I should list that. I get a "can't run .then() on undefined" or similar. When i console.log listKey it's undefined, when I console.log the listPushRef it's an unresolved promise.

Comment: Is database defined? Would seem something isn't promised here and so far it may not be in this function

Comment: The list gets written to the database so I would assume it is. I can check in a moment if theres a problem there.

Comment: Think about that, database is a promise event, it will deliver but if code continued and executed the following lines before the promise finished you might have an undefined value there. Wild guess but check if you're skipping lines before the call is made. You can run console.log(1) up  to 5 to see if it counts right! ;) if order falls apart you likely sent database way too early.

Comment: Something weird is going on here, listsRef.push does not behave the way it should. 

If I log listPushRef on android I get, with await: 
Cannot read property 'then' of undefined, 
without await: 
{"_promise": undefined, "_ref": undefined}
on ios I get:
"https://***.firebaseio.com/lists/-MZwMJp8ms2f48Jc3RYE" with or without await

Comment: You're close, not sure what it can be tho

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, I didn't have too much time to spend on this so I had to go around the problem by creating my own keys.

So instead of using `listPushRef.key` I generated a UUID. Not optimal but it works.